# Is it typical to experience zoom creep with the Canon EF 24-105mm F/4 L IS USM?

Tags: lens, canon, troubleshooting, zoom-creep, zoom-lock

I noticed this more than once. Whenever I'm in the range from 24mm to somewhere between 35mm and 50mm, the lens starts moving if I'm fixing it vertically with its front element facing the ceiling or the floor, is this a problem with my own lens or it's a general problem with this lens?

Comment: You have to look into a company called Lens Band. They provide a silicone band that fits the barrel of the zoom lens. Here is a link: http://lensband.com

Comment: I also have this trouble with a recent lens (less than a year old)...

Comment: Common problem on this lens. I have two, purchased 2012 and 2009. The older one creeps, the newer one doesn't.

Comment: How to fix it: https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/109398/how-to-fix-zoom-creep-in-canon-ef-24-105mm-f-4l-is-usm-lens

Answer (score 3):

A quick search shows that you're not alone with this problem for that lens. (I don't have that lens myself, so I can't comment from experience). Since it is an **L**-series lens, you might want to just take it to Canon for them to service it.

Alternatively, if you want a DIY solution, the simplest fix might just be a thick rubber band or a piece of gaffer tape. [Here's a collection of different DIY methods people have attempted for fixing the problem.](http://lensband.com/diy/)

Answer (score 0):

My 24-105 does not have creep.  I just tried mine in a vertical position looking up and down.  I wiggled it around to try to induce a bit of creep.  None.

Answer (score 0):

I have two of these lenses and have never experienced this. I would expect them to be stable, as L series lenses are expected to perform well. They are not the same though. One works with all my autofocus systems and the other only works on my 1DsMIII. I only bring this up to point out that not every lens is the same.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, yes. Very typical. My EF 24-105 f/4L IS USM developed zoom creep after about four or five years.  It's probably one of my most-used lenses.  I did attempt peeling back the rubber on the zoom ring and using the screws to adjust the tension, but the creep returned pretty quickly.  While a big flat rubber band, like the lensband, can be used to add enough friction to stop the ring from turning on its own when the zoom is "pulled" out by gravity, I found it enough of an irritation in use, that I just live with the creep.

Answer (score -1):

Most not-top-of-the-line zoom lenses have this problem, as far as i know.

This is a guess, but i am assuming lenses which have no external moving parts might minimize this issue...but then again, this might have to do with the fact that these kinds of lenses are usually nearer to the top of the line.

To counteract it, fixing the lens on place with tape might be a quick and dirty solution (if the lens is retrofocal, which yours seems to be, and nothing moves externally while focusing).

Comment: I thought that this lens is _luxurious_ since it belongs to the Canon's _Luxury _ series :(

Comment: oh well...you can always buy a prime lens and all these troubles will be gone! additionally, i think my cheap nikon 18-55 kit lens doesn't have zoom creep...it has too little glass to weigh it down :D

Comment: A agree with JoseNunFerreira. I've never seen a low-end lens with zoom creep. Only heavy lenses do that and some of those even have a zoom lock button.

Comment: Does that button allow for stopping anywhere in the zoom range, or just on the shortest focal distance (for transport, etc)?