# How to fix zoom creep in Canon EF 24-105mm F/4L IS USM lens?

Tags: lens, canon, zoom, zoom-creep, camera-modification

I have the first version of the Canon EF 24-105mm F/4L IS USM lens. It has
annoying zoom creep. If I walk around with this lens, with the camera hanging
from my neck, occasionally the zoom automatically extends from 24mm. This
happens rarely enough that checking the zoom ring every 5-10 minutes is enough
to stay most of the time at 24mm, when walking around -- I counted
approximately three occurrences of zoom creep per hour when walking around.
There is no zoom lock in this lens. I have never found the zoom ring too hard
to rotate, contrary to
[the criticism by
Ken Rockwell](https://kenrockwell.com/canon/lenses/24-105mm.htm).

I would like the zoom mechanism to be stiffer so that the zoom doesn't creep.
How to achieve this? I wouldn't want to throw away a perfectly fine
second-hand-purchase and purchase a 1200 USD new lens instead. The lens is
absolutely flawless apart from this zoom creep issue.

Related, although this question asks about the typicality of the issue and not
how to fix it:
[Is it typical to experience zoom creep with the Canon EF 24-105mm F/4 L IS USM?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/23254/is-it-typical-to-experience-zoom-creep-with-the-canon-ef-24-105mm-f-4-l-is-usm)

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary to throw away the lens, as zoom creep on this lens is
trivial to be fixed (or some could say worked around).

There is a gap between rotating parts, between the distance scale and the zoom
ring of the lens. Purchase a 20 USD collection of O-rings of variable sizes,
and put an O-ring over this gap. The O-ring I used is marked F-32 and it
appears to have an inner diameter of two inches and tube diameter of 3 mm so
it's relatively thick. It requires a bit of force to put the small O-ring
around the large lens (diameter 79mm at this location), but once this has been
done, the O-ring resists rotation of the lens so much that the zoom creep no
longer occurs. The zoom ring is markedly stiffer to turn as well after this
modification, much to the horror of Ken Rockwell. Problem solved!

Depending on the severity of the zoom creep, it may be necessary in extreme
cases to use an even smaller inner diameter O-ring. Furthermore, the tube
diameter of the O-ring probably affects what is the optimal inner diameter of
the O-ring (thicker-tubed O-rings require less difference between the O-ring
inner diameter and the lens outer diameter), so don't treat "2 inches" as an
absolute truth.

The modification likely improves the weather resistance of the lens, as well.
It is practically invisible from a distance: as the O-ring is black and small,
nobody notices you purchased poor-quality gear and had to modify it. For
someone to notice the modification, one needs to look at the lens very closely.

[image: Lens with O-ring]

Others who have solved the zoom creep:

- Rubber band, not o-ring, in another location: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UQb5GIwYgdw
- DIY rubber band zoom lock: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q3Za0DuX9EY
- A differently sized O ring in last answer of first page (tube diameter 0.6mm x inner diameter 30mm so there's more stretch in this): https://www.dpreview.com/forums/thread/2845637
- A proper fix: https://www.reddit.com/r/photography/comments/204tr2/how_to_fix_canon_24105l_zoom_creep/

Answer (score 1):

A zoom lock included in the design of a lens was more common back 30-40 years ago than it is today.

Many experienced photographers today use something that is almost the butt of jokes about duct tape fixing anything when they wish to keep a zoom lens at a specific setting for a series of photos: gaffer's tape. It holds well enough but doesn't leave any residue once removed.

[image]

There are several other methods involving wide rubber bands. There's even a company that makes them and specifically markets for this use: [lens bands](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0050KHY5E). Most such bands aren't much different from the wrist bands that have become popular for showing support for various causes. Depending on the size of your lens, one of the wrist bands might fit the bill. I have a rubber wristband on my very well used EF 24-105mm f/4 L IS to prevent zoom creep.

[image]

You can also find a plethora of DIY methods by searching the internet for "fix zoom creep". Some of these methods are lens specific. Including the lens name in your search will help find those specific to your model lens.